# Evaluation of $\Omega_E(E,N)$ for Ideal gas

Tags: statistical-mechanics, ideal-gas

I'm reading *An Introduction to Statistical Mechanics and Thermodynamics* By Robert H. Swendsen

---

In section 6.2.1, They find the
$$\Omega_E(E,N)=\int\cdots\int\delta \left(E-\sum_1^N\frac{|\vec{p}_j|^2}{2m}\right)dp_1\cdots dp_{3N}$$
$$=\int_0^\infty S_n p^{3N-1}\delta \left(E-\frac{p^2}{2m}\right)dp$$
Using $p^2=\sum|\vec{p}_j|^2$ and $x=p^2/2m\Rightarrow pdp=mdx$
$$\Omega_E(E,N)=S_n\int p^{3N-1}\delta\left(E-\frac{p^2}{2m}\right)dp=S_n\int(2mx)^{(3N-1)/2}\delta(E-x)mdx$$
$$\Omega_E(E,N)=S_n(2mE)^{(3N-1)/2}$$

---

I don't understand, the substitution of $x$, Why they haven't put $dp=mdx/p$?

Comment: Can you check for typos? Some of your equations seem dimensionally inconsistent. And what is $n$ in $S_n$?

Comment: @G.Smith $n$ in $S_n$ is simply dim of the space which in this case is $3N$. I have just written what was in the book. Can you point out equations, which are inconsistent? Ignoring the fact $h^{N}$.

Comment: In the next-to-the-last line of equations, I don’t see how the dimensions  are the same in the integral over $p$ and the integral over $x$. Are you sure you wrote the exponent correctly?

Comment: I don’t understand why the author would not pick either $n$ or $N$. Writing equations with *both*, when $n=3N$, seems silly.

Comment: @G.Smith The inconsistency comes from the fact that the author hasn't substituted $dx$ correctly, He left the $p$ on the denominator.

Comment: @G.Smith Do I put the screenshort of the book?

Comment: No screenshot. There shouldn’t be a $p$ in the denominator; the point of changing variables from $p$ to $x$ is to *eliminate* $p$. Instead there should be a $\sqrt{2mx}$ in the denominator, which would give a different exponent.

Comment: I’m not convinced that the final formula is correct either. Maybe this is just a poor-quality book.